# Apache Zeppelin on windows 10... Not working

Tags: windows-10, apache-zeppelin

Intall zeppelin and make enviroment path on windows 
and zeppelin.cmd on bin folder....
it's not working... 
i can't find any problem path enviroment... plz help me.
just follow the install information on zeppelin website.

```
 D:\Apps\zeppelin>.\bin\zeppelin.cmd
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/lib/interpreter/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
     WARN [2017-04-18 17:09:07,601] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:97) - Failed to load configuration, proceeding with a default
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:09:07,657] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:109) - Server Host: 0.0.0.0
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:09:07,657] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:111) - Server Port: 8080
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:09:07,658] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:115) - Context Path: /
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:09:07,663] ({main} ZeppelinConfiguration.java[create]:116) - Zeppelin Version: 0.7.1
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:09:07,700] ({main} Log.java[initialized]:186) - Logging initialized @708ms
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:09:07,781] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[setupWebAppContext]:341) - ZeppelinServer Webapp path: D:\Apps\zeppelin\webapps
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:09:08,027] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:185) - Starting zeppelin server
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:09:08,030] ({main} Server.java[doStart]:327) - jetty-9.2.15.v20160210
                                   INFO [2017-04-18 17:09:57,251] ({main} StandardDescriptorProcessor.java[visitServlet]:297) - NO JSP Support for /, did not find org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
     WARN [2017-04-18 17:22:32,504] ({main} Helium.java[loadConf]:101) - D:\Apps\zeppelin\conf/helium.json does not exists
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:32,517] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[<init>]:127) - InterpreterRootPath: D:\Apps\zeppelin\interpreter
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:32,518] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[<init>]:129) - InterpreterBindingPath: D:\Apps\zeppelin\conf\interpreter.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:32,639] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/alluxio/zeppelin-alluxio-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:32,661] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/angular/zeppelin-angular-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:32,687] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/bqsql/zeppelin-bigquery-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:32,723] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/cassandra/zeppelin-cassandra_2.11-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:32,786] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/elasticsearch/zeppelin-elasticsearch-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:32,811] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/file/zeppelin-file-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:32,920] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/flink/zeppelin-flink_2.11-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:33,043] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/hbase/zeppelin-hbase-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:33,107] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/ignite/zeppelin-ignite_2.11-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:33,126] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/jdbc/zeppelin-jdbc-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:33,137] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/kylin/zeppelin-kylin-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:33,248] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/lens/zeppelin-lens-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:33,293] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/livy/zeppelin-livy-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:33,314] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/md/zeppelin-markdown-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:33,467] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/pig/zeppelin-pig-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
     WARN [2017-04-18 17:22:33,498] ({main} Interpreter.java[register]:406) - Static initialization is deprecated for interpreter sql, You should change it to use interpreter-setting.json in your jar or interpreter/{interpreter}/interpreter-setting.json
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:33,500] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:300) - Interpreter psql.sql found. class=org.apache.zeppelin.postgresql.PostgreSqlInterpreter
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:34,239] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/python/zeppelin-python-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:34,368] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/sh/zeppelin-shell-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:34,924] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[registerInterpreterFromResource]:377) - Reading interpreter-setting.json from jar:file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/interpreter/spark/zeppelin-spark_2.11-0.7.1.jar!/interpreter-setting.json
    DEBUG [2017-04-18 17:22:34,928] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:316) - Registered: psql.sql -> org.apache.zeppelin.postgresql.PostgreSqlInterpreter. Properties: {postgresql.password={envName=null, propertyName=null, defaultValue=, description=The PostgreSQL user password}, postgresql.max.result={envName=null, propertyName=null, defaultValue=1000, description=Max number of SQL result to display.}, postgresql.user={envName=null, propertyName=null, defaultValue=gpadmin, description=The PostgreSQL user name}, postgresql.url={envName=null, propertyName=null, defaultValue=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/, description=The URL for PostgreSQL.}, postgresql.driver.name={envName=null, propertyName=null, defaultValue=org.postgresql.Driver, description=    JDBC Driver Name}}
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,930] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name ignite
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,933] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name python
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,945] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name jdbc
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,950] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name psql
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,953] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name lens
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,955] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name pig
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,965] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name flink
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,967] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name angular
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,970] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name livy
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,972] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name file
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,982] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name elasticsearch
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,985] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name cassandra
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,988] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name sh
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:34,998] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name spark
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:35,000] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name md
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:35,004] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name alluxio
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:35,006] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name bigquery
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:35,016] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name hbase
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:35,019] ({main} InterpreterSettingManager.java[init]:332) - InterpreterSettingRef name kylin
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.createSingletonInstance(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:382)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.createApplicationInstance(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:454)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.createServerFromApplication(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:432)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.init(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:93)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:616)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:396)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:187)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterSettingManager.loadFromFile(InterpreterSettingManager.java:167)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterSettingManager.init(InterpreterSettingManager.java:335)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterSettingManager.<init>(InterpreterSettingManager.java:151)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.<init>(ZeppelinServer.java:141)
            ... 29 more
     WARN [2017-04-18 17:22:35,212] ({main} ContextHandler.java[log]:2062) - unavailable
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Resource class org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer can not be instantiated due to InvocationTargetException
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.createSingletonInstance(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:396)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.createApplicationInstance(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:454)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.createServerFromApplication(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:432)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.init(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:93)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:616)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:396)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:187)
    4??18, 2017 5:22:35 ?ㅽ썑 com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
    ?뺣낫: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
      org.apache.zeppelin.rest
    4??18, 2017 5:22:35 ?ㅽ썑 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
    ?뺣낫: Root resource classes found:
      class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.ConfigurationsRestApi
      class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.HeliumRestApi
      class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.NotebookRepoRestApi
      class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.InterpreterRestApi
      class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.NotebookRestApi
      class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.CredentialRestApi
      class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.SecurityRestApi
      class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.LoginRestApi
      class org.apache.zeppelin.rest.ZeppelinRestApi
    4??18, 2017 5:22:35 ?ㅽ썑 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
    ?뺣낫: No provider classes found.
    4??18, 2017 5:22:35 ?ㅽ썑 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
    ?뺣낫: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.13 06/29/2012 05:14 PM'
    4??18, 2017 5:22:36 ?ㅽ썑 com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
    寃쎄퀬: The following warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
      WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.zeppelin.rest.CredentialRestApi.getCredentials(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException,java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, should not consume any entity.
      WARNING: A HTTP GET method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.zeppelin.rest.InterpreterRestApi.listInterpreter(java.lang.String), should not consume any entity.
      WARNING: A sub-resource method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.zeppelin.rest.NotebookRestApi.createNote(java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException, with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
      WARNING: A sub-resource method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response org.apache.zeppelin.rest.NotebookRestApi.getNoteList() throws java.io.IOException, with URI template, "/", is treated as a resource method
     WARN [2017-04-18 17:22:36,250] ({main} WebAppContext.java[doStart]:514) - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@51b279c9{/,file:/D:/Apps/zeppelin/webapps/webapp/,STARTING}{D:\Apps\zeppelin\zeppelin-web-0.7.1.war}
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Resource class org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer can not be instantiated due to InvocationTargetException
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.createSingletonInstance(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:396)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.createApplicationInstance(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:454)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.createServerFromApplication(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:432)
            at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.servlet.CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.init(CXFNonSpringJaxrsServlet.java:93)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:616)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:396)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:871)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:298)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1349)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1342)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:163)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:387)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:354)
            at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
            at org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer.main(ZeppelinServer.java:187)
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:36,412] ({main} AbstractConnector.java[doStart]:266) - Started ServerConnector@511816c0{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:36,412] ({main} Server.java[doStart]:379) - Started @809435ms
     INFO [2017-04-18 17:22:36,418] ({main} ZeppelinServer.java[main]:192) - Done, zeppelin server started
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same java exception on Windows 10 with the Zeppelin 0.7.1 release preventing the localhost from starting. My workaround was rolling back versions and running from Zeppelin 0.7.0 release. Make sure that you have Hadoop installed as well, I am using version 2.7.1-1.

Comment: Thx for ur time 
I'm gonna make it Zeppelin 0.7.0 and comment it

Comment: I had the same problem and rolling back to 0.7.0 indeed solved it, thanks!